# SQLAlchemy MySQL - Optimal method to update a table that needs to be frequently entirely updated. Questions on implementation

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, sql-update, temp-tables

My use case;

My code runs multiple Scrapy spiders on different US counties to collect property data on every property. This is done by looping through a list of PINS/Parcels(100k to 200k) which are appended to the same URLS over and over, collecting sales data on each parcel or property, and storing that data on its respective county table one row at a time. My use case involves updating these tables frequently(once a week or so) to collect trends on sales data. Out of 100K properties, it can be that only a few acquired new sales records, but I would not know unless I went through all of them.

I currently began implementing this via pipeline below which essentially accomplishes getting the data in the table on the first run when the table is a clean slate. However when re-running to refresh data, I'm obviously unable to insert rows that contain the same unique ID and would need to update the row instead. My unique ID for each data point is its parcel number.

My questions-

```
    1. What is the optimal method to update a database table that 
    requires a full refresh(all rows) frequently?
```

My guess so far based on research I've done is replacing the old table with a new temporary table. This is because it would be quicker(I think) to insert all data into a new table than to query each item in the old table, see if it has changed, and if changed, modify that row. This can be accomplished by inserting all data into the temporary table first, then replacing the old table with the new one.

If my method of implementation is optimal, how would I go about implementing this?

Should I use some kind of data migration module(panda?)- What would happen if I dropped the old table, and program was interrupted at this point prior to new table replacing it.

---

```
class PierceDataPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates tables.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self,item,spider):
        """
        This method is called for every item pipeline component
        """
        session = self.Session()

        propertyDataTable = PierceCountyPropertyData()

        propertyDataTable.parcel = item["parcel"]
        propertyDataTable.mailing_address = item["mailing_address"]
        propertyDataTable.owner_name = item["owner_name"]

        propertyDataTable.county = item["county"]
        propertyDataTable.site_address = item["site_address"]
        propertyDataTable.property_type = item["property_type"]
        propertyDataTable.occupancy = item["occupancy"]
        propertyDataTable.year_built = item["year_built"]
        propertyDataTable.adj_year_built = item["adj_year_built"]
        propertyDataTable.units = item["units"]
        propertyDataTable.bedrooms = item["bedrooms"]
        propertyDataTable.baths = item["baths"]
        propertyDataTable.siding_type = item["siding_type"]
        propertyDataTable.stories = item["stories"]
        propertyDataTable.lot_square_footage = item["lot_square_footage"]
        propertyDataTable.lot_acres = item["lot_acres"]

        propertyDataTable.current_balance_due = item["current_balance_due"]
        propertyDataTable.tax_year_1 = item["tax_year_1"]
        propertyDataTable.tax_year_2 = item["tax_year_2"]
        propertyDataTable.tax_year_3 = item["tax_year_3"]
        propertyDataTable.tax_year_1_assessed = item["tax_year_1_assessed"]
        propertyDataTable.tax_year_2_assessed = item["tax_year_2_assessed"]
        propertyDataTable.tax_year_3_assessed = item["tax_year_3_assessed"]

        propertyDataTable.sale1_price = item["sale1_price"]
        propertyDataTable.sale1_date = item["sale1_date"]
        propertyDataTable.sale2_date = item["sale2_date"]
        propertyDataTable.sale2_price = item["sale2_price"]

        try:
            session.add(propertyDataTable)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

        return item
```

---

Comment: My first thought is that if you are hoping to analyse trends in data for properties in different areas, then overwriting the old data isn't the way to go. If you get property data for country x this week, and do it again next week but overwrite last weeks data, how can you analyse the trends?

Comment: I should of elaborated - the are two tables here that can be updated. 1.) A property information table(site address, owner name etc..)  if a row changes here I would just want to update it with the current data. 2.) Sales records, each property will have 1,2,3.. sales. The county will add a new sales record to the previous ones. In this case my sales table can be implemented by using multiple rows.  I would no longer use parcel as the unique Id because there would be multiple rows with the same parcel num, each representing a sale. I'd simply add more rows on refresh

Comment: I think an Upsert is what you are looking for? [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for the property info table. [SQLAlchemy supports it as of 1.2](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: @SuperShoot I looked into a what you wrote which lead to a few interesting things like ON Duplicate Key Update and others which were all in same line of thinking with yours. However I don't think that's the proper solution here- I will need to query every row and see if it has changed in my use case. I think this would be significantly lower in performance than a bunch of inserts into a new temporary table and replacing the original table